# How to get blob-URL after file upload in azure using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded the files on azure blob container but how can I get the url of a that uploaded file using java.
I have connectionString of the azure portal.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I use the Azure Blob storage v12, you could refer to the below code. Further more information about this SDK you could check this source code:[Azure Storage Blob client library for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob).

```
        String connectStr = "storage account connection";

        // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("container name");

        BlobClient blobClient=containerClient.getBlobClient("blob name");

        System.out.println(blobClient.getBlobUrl());
```

[image]

Comment: but what if my blob is not public and I want to create a SAS url.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 String blobKey = <key to your blob> 
 // Create a blob service client
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

 CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(name);

 // get reference to the Blob you want to generate the SAS for:
 CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobKey);
```

and call

```
blob.getUri();
```

Comment: but what is container?

Comment: Container client

Comment: I am trying by doing something     "BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);"    but it is not working can you post the complete function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use container client?

Comment: but in updated answer there is a problem with "account.createCloudBlobClient()". the account object is not defined

Comment: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer/getBlockBlobReference